# for loop calculates the same value each time

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a recurrence relation that will return me the kth term. But I am receiving the same output when I change the k value. Here is my code:

```
int recurrence(int a, int b, int k, int u0, int u1) {
  int u = u0;
  int uu = u1;

  for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    uu = a*u1 + b*u0;

  return uu;
}

int recurrence2(int a1, int b1, int k1, int u4, int u5) {
  int u = u4;
  int uu = u5;

  for (int i = 0; i < k1; i++)
    uu = a1*u5 + b1*u4;


  return uu;

}

int main() {
  int h;
  h = recurrence(7, 1, 5, 3, 5 );
  int g;
  g = recurrence2(17, 11, 2, 1, 2);

  cout << "The result is:  " << h;
  cout << "The result is : " << g;
}
```

Comment: Changing the value of `k` only changes how many times you preform `uu = a*u1 + b*u0;`. Regardless of the number of times you do it, the value of `a`, `u1`, `b` and `u0` are the same, so the result is always the same.

Comment: Did you try to _step through_ your code, using the debugger?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i noticed that now. Therefore my question is, how can i make the values f u0 and u1 change taking into consideration their previous ones. For example, i did the math on my notebook and if U0 is 3 and U1 is 5, U3 should be 38. If i compile the program now , the output is 38 but how do i make it to proceed further ?

Comment: @user7716102 There's a hint to a way in the name: "recurrence" and "recursion" have the same root.

Answer (score 1):

You evaluate the same values in expression in the loop, so result would not change regardless how many times you execute it. Looks like this is what you need:

```
int recurrence(int a, int b, int k, int u0, int u1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        auto tmp = a*u1 + b*u0;
        u0 = u1;
        u1 = tmp;
    }
    return u1;
}
```

or simpler:

```
int recurrence(int a, int b, int k, int u0, int u1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        u0 = a*u1 + b*u0;
        std::swap( u1, u0 );
    }
    return u1;
}
```

second function needs to be changed the same way.

PS you asked how could you maintain state of variables for further invocations, best way is to have `class` that maintains it:

```
class Recurrence {
     int m_a;
     int m_b;
     int m_u0;
     int m_u1;

 public:
     Recurrence( int a, int b, int u0, int u1 ) :
         m_a( a ),
         m_b( b ),
         m_u0( u0 ),
         m_u1( u1 )
     {
     }

     int value() const { return m_u1; }

     void interate()
     {
          m_u0 = m_a * m_u1 + m_b * m_u0;
          std::swap( m_u0, m_u1 );
     }

     void interateN( int n )
     {
          for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) iterate();
     }
};

int main()
{
     Recurence recurence( 7, 1, 3, 5 );
     recurence.iterateN( 5 );
     int h = recurence.value();
     recurence.iterateN( 5 ); // continue
     ...
}
```

In reality you may want to have that class more generic - for example use different number of arguments, different types, store them in array etc. This code just to show you the idea.

Comment: Yes, brilliant. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @user7716102 it would be appreciating if you accept the answer.